# Setting minimum size limit for a window minimization of browser?

Tags: javascript, html, css, browser, cross-browser

Is there a way to manually set the minimum size of a browser window across all browsers?

Comment: if you mean to restrict the browser window then a definitive **no** (*for good reason*). If you mean the actual site then `min-width` is your friend..

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli _"definitive **no**"_ is definitely incorrect — [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16174183/356541) provides a solution which works in Chrome. I humbly suggest anybody thinking of upvoting the comment above also think about downvoting my answer, for the sake of posterity!

Comment: @Barney the OP states "***for all browser support***" and also you solution will only work if the window is opened through `window.open`. Of'course your answer should not be downvoted as it provides a solution to certain scenarios and is a good addition to the question/answers for future reference..

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli I suppose you're right — I mean on an iPhone you have no control at all over a window's size, which I guess by itself technically warrants a "definitive no"…

Comment: "Good answers are definitely appreciated" - you don't say?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can try

```
body {  min-width:600px; }
```

You will get a horizontal scrollbar once the viewport gets less than 600px. This will work in only modern browsers supporting min-width CSS property.

I don't think it is possible to restrict user from resizing, and it shouldn't be!

Comment: You _can_ technically restrict users from resizing (see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16174183/356541)), although I'd agree with your opinion that you shouldn't be able to.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me in Chrome (jsbin - https://jsbin.com/nuzemogaxa/edit?html,css,output )

Answer (score 30):

You'll have to use Javascript and create the window in question for this to work most of the time, since tabbed bowsers won't let you redefine the size of the window containing other tabs. Even then, some browsers won't let you do this.

Using [`window.open`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/window.open), you can make a given window of size 640 * 480 by specifying:

```
window.open('http://www.your.url/','yourWindowsName','width=640,height=480');
```

Within the window you can try and [`resizeTo`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.resizeTo) height and width triggered by the `resize` event handler like the following:

```
function resizeToMinimum(){
  var minimum    = [640, 480];
  var current    = [window.outerWidth, window.outerHeight];
  var restricted = [];
  var i          = 2;

  while(i-- > 0){
    restricted[i] = minimum[i] > current[i] ? minimum[i] : current[i];
  }

  window.resizeTo(current[0], current[1]);
}

window.addEventListener('resize', resizeToMinimum, false)
```

You should take into account that both behaviours above are contentious, and what you're describing effectively restricts the freedom of the user to use their browser as they see fit. As such, I wouldn't expect this to work everywhere — but in places where it does, this is the code that will allow you to do so.

Comment: Could someone please explain to me this line ```while(i-- > 0){
    restricted[i] = minimum[i] > current[i] ? minimum[i] : current[i];
  }``` I don't understand the meaning of```-- >; ? nor :``` and I couldn't find it online

Comment: `i--` is a [_postfix_ decrement operation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Decrement); `>` is [greater than](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Greater_than_operator); and `x ? y : z` is a [ternary operation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)! Sorry for lack of elaboration but the links should clarify!

Comment: Should this say `window.resizeTo(restricted[0], restricted[1]);`?

Comment: I would just note the following: "It's not possible to resize a window or tab that wasn’t created by window.open(). It's also not possible to resize when the window has multiple tabs".  Src: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/resizeTo

Answer (score 3):

```
function resizeToMinimum(w,h){
    w=w>window.outerWidth?w:window.outerWidth;
    h=h>window.outerHeight?h:window.outerHeight;
    window.resizeTo(w, h);
};
window.addEventListener('resize', function(){resizeToMinimum(100,100)}, false)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution for ensuring actual minimum content width and height, which includes dealing with different browser's "chrome" dimensions. This doesn't work with Firefox, but I've tested it in Edge and Chrome.

```
function ensureMinimumWindowSize(width, height) {
    var tooThin = (width > window.innerWidth);
    var tooShort = (height > window.innerHeight);

    if (tooThin || tooShort) {
        var deltaWidth = window.outerWidth - window.innerWidth;
        var deltaHeight = window.outerHeight - window.innerHeight;

        width = tooThin ? width + deltaWidth : window.outerWidth;
        height = tooShort ? height + deltaHeight : window.outerHeight;

        // Edge not reporting window outer size correctly
        if (/Edge/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
            width -= 16;
            height -= 8;
        }

        window.resizeTo(width, height);
    }
}

var resizeTimer;
window.addEventListener('resize', function(event) {
    clearTimeout(resizeTimer);
    resizeTimer = setTimeout(function () {
        ensureMinimumWindowSize(<width>,<height>);
    }, 250);
}, false);
```