# Restrict the user from resizing the browser window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is question is discussed before (somewhat similar).[Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16173965/setting-minimum-size-limit-for-a-window-minimization-of-browser)

But I have a different scenario from the other question.
My web application is mainly for Internet Explorer only. And this is going to be used in desktop/laptops and not in mobiles or any other devices.

So I need to restrict the minimize and maximize of the web application using javascript/jquery. Window size is same all the time.
At the same time I don't want to go for window.open() method. Because this is a single window application, no new window required.

Any suggestions or advice ?

Comment: Does this help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10610899/disable-browser-window-resize?

Comment: @DeepakMishra It doesn't seem to work. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score -4):

You can first determine a definite size.

```
var sizes = [window.width,window.height]; 

$(window).resize(function()
{
window.resizeTo(size[0],size[1]);
});
```

Just try this one

Comment: do not copy paste the answer from other post. Ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10610899/disable-browser-window-resize