# How to set a fix min width size for window resizing?

Tags: html, css, width

Is there a way to restrict the minimum window width to be resized to a width smaller than `x` pixels. Can I achive this just using CSS or HTML, e.g. `meta` tags?

I tried setting

```
body {
    min-width: 420px;
}
```

and this sets a min width for my body. But I can still resize the windows width to smaller than this width value.

Comment: So you want to restrict the browser from being resized smaller than a given value?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16173965/setting-minimum-size-limit-for-a-window-minimization-of-browser

Answer (score 1):

You can not control the size of the browser window. You can use CSS to set min-width and min-height properties to ensure your page layout stays same.

You may want to control the size of the browser window which opens when a viewer accesses your web page.(Using javascript)

```
<body onload="changeScreenSize(500,300)">
```