# How to have different alignments in one div(nav)?

Tags: html, css, layout, alignment, text-alignment

In this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vtrec4oL/

I want `#leftSide` to align on the left end of my `<nav>` and the rest in the center.

But I want my page to be as compatible as possible to window resizing so I prefer not to use margin/padding.

Also I would love to achieve this with no additional element if possible.

Does anyone know how to do this only with css?

Comment: Lower case t, so `text-align: center;`. Also put space between bracket and selector, `nav a#leftSide {`

Comment: sry, those were typos:)

Comment: Sorry if that seemed mean, didn't mean for it to. :)

Comment: @King its alright!but you know!actually you can use Text-align instead of text-align and if will work the same in any known browser, also, that space before the bracket is not needed.

Comment: Yeah I was aware of that, it just bothered me for some reason. I had a minor OCD attack. Sorry about that.

Comment: haha!so that was an order!sir yes sir!sry!i thought it was an answer!;)happy programming buddy!vote up my question if you are also curious for the answer;)

Comment: Aran, are you open to using a flexbox? That would accomplish what you want quickly and easily, and with minimal code. Only thing no support for IE 8 & 9.

Comment: well, i came up with a solution myself! But it ruins my vertical align a little bit!so, tell me about your flexbox!is it the same as, display:flex?

Comment: i think this title is better because its answers are also answers for how to have some elements aligned in left and some in right, some in middle some in right etc. and i think the code should be mentioned in the beginning bc we first have to define `#leftSide` and then talk about it.but thank you for the enters! i didn't know how to enter!its strange you have to enter twice to achieve one line break!

Comment: You can also use `br` tags to create line breaks in your questions.

Comment: @Michael_B thanks a lot:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want `a#gnbii` to align on the left end of my nav bar and the
>   rest of the links in the center.
>
> But I want my page to be as compatible as possible to window resizing
>   so I prefer not to use margin/padding.
>
> Also I would love to achieve this with no additional element if
>   possible.

With a combination of CSS **flexbox** and **positioning** properties all  requirements can be met.

First, add an ID to your `a#gnbii` parent container:

```
<li class="gnb" id="align-left"> /* NEW - ID added */
<a class="gnb" id="gnbii" href="home.html">
<img id="gnbii" src="../images/instagram icon/1.png" alt="aranpuzzle.ir" height="40px">
<img id="gnbii" src="../images/instagram icon/2.png" alt="aranpuzzle.ir" height="40px">
</a>
</li>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
ul {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
}

#align-left {
    position: absolute;
    left: 2%;
}
```

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/6pmfc87h/3/

***Here's what's happening...***

- The `ul` becomes a flexbox with `display: flex` applied. Each `li` is now lined up in a row, which is the default behavior for flexbox children (known as "flex items").
- `justify-content: center` centers child elements along the main axis. In this case, horizontally.
- `align-items: center` centers child elements along the cross axis. In this case, vertically.
- `position: relative` establishes the nearest positioned ancestor for absolute positioning.
- `position: absolute` moves the last `li` to the left edge of its nearest positioned ancestor.

To learn more about flexbox here's a good reference: [A Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

To learn more about absolute position check this out: [MDN `position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

---

**UPDATE** (based on comments; for smaller screens)

> i want it to slide to right as much as possible instead of overlapping...

Okay, so we can add `white-space: nowrap` to the `ul` so the nav items always stay in a row.

Then declare a media query to shift everything to the right on smaller screens:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) { 
    ul { justify-content: flex-start; }  /* note: site is RTL */
    #align-left { position: static; }
}
```

UPDATED DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/6pmfc87h/4/

> ...and when there is no more space to slide right, i prefer that then
>   the explorer doesn't let the user resize the width of the window any
>   thiner!

Are you sure this is what you want to do? There are [some JavaScript methods](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=browser%20set%20window%20size) that set browser window size, but I'm not sure they're completely reliable across all browsers. More importantly, I don't think this adheres to best practices. In my view, a user should be allowed to re-size their browser window however much the browser natively allows. [[Learn more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16173965/setting-minimum-size-limit-for-a-window-minimization-of-browser).]

You're better off focusing on the areas where you have more control as a web developer. You can set a `min-width` declaration telling the browser that your element can't get any narrower. Or you can use media queries to change things around to fit on smaller screens.

Comment: You changed your HTML and fiddle demo while I was preparing my answer. However, this answer still applies to your revised question and covers all your requirements. If you have any questions just post a comment.

Comment: i'm sry for that edit, but i realized there were too much irrelevant details in it so i wanted to keep it short and general:)

Comment: thank you so much for you detailed, well explained, answer!Well, your answer fixes the problem with my answer, that the parts that should have been in the middle were not exactly in the middle, but the problem with it is the interference of the items as the window's width is resized, and also it doesn't fix the vertical-align problem, probably you didn't notice that bc of your padding, try to add `*{padding:0;margin:0;}` in the beginning of your css, hopefully you will notice then:)

Comment: No problem with the edit. Your revision is as also quite clear.

Comment: How do you want the nav bar to appear on smaller screen size?

Comment: As the window resizes smaller the nav items could all stay in one row. Overlapping can be prevented with a `min-width` declaration. The items could also shift to a column alignment with `justify-content: column`. Or something else. Let me know and I'll update my answer.

Comment: i want it to slide to right as much as possible instead of overlapping and when there is no more space to slide right, i prefer that then the explorer doesn't let the user resize the width of the window any thiner!if not i don't care what happens then!i will just alert a warning!but on phone and etc i will do it with smaller fonts etc!

Comment: well, i think i have my answer already!i just added a little padding and the alignment is fixed and the float slides as i want and the images in the left side aren't too thick so they doesn't make so much difference for the central text alignment:)thank you so much for your time and advices:)i learned a lot from you:)happy programing;):)

Comment: will i get reputation if no one can answer my q for two days and i post and answer myself and check my own answer?

Comment: Also, there is no such thing as "no one can answer my q for two days". Open questions (like yours) can receive answers anytime. I think you may have been referring to the "bounty" eligiblity, which is something else. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107995/question-eligible-for-bounty-in-2-days-why

Comment: And yes, an upvote and checkmark equals 25 rep points to answerer. You say you "gave" them to me, but I like to think I earned them :-)

Comment: i said that bc you cant accept your own answer within two days:)thank you so much:)and so up voting a comment has no effect?:D!consider an up vote for my q btw if you haven't yet!:D!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to align an specific  element, just create a class and add it to that element.
If you want to align last child or first child, use :first-child or :last-child selector in your css.
Remember that #leftSide is an ID, do will affect one element, instead use a class.

Comment: Show me your code or paste it in a jsfiddle to help you.

Comment: i'm to lazy for that!i prefer to be patient instead:)thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you tried `nav li#leftSide {
    text-align:left;
}`

Comment: @aran, one purpose of Stack Overflow is to create a repository of questions and answers that can help people in the future. Posting your code makes your question more valuable to the broader community (not to mention it would likely give your question more attention and better quality answers).

Comment: @Michael_B i know, but i though if sb can answer this q with code, they can also do without!and the thing is i program with my laptop and here i only have internet on my phone, i see i have to make a hotspot!:D!bc noone is answering!(if i edit now, will it promote the question or i'd better delete this and post a new one?

Comment: Yes, if you edit the question it will be sent back to the top of the "Recently Active" list. No need to delete and start over.

Comment: @dacastro4: i made the fiddle:)

Answer (score 0):

add the following to your css:

```
#leftSide{
    float:left;
}
```

But, if i were you; I would add a few pixels of margin-left for the left picture so its not on the edge.

Unfortunately, my solution ruins your vertical-align a bit!