# set min-height of a html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using `min-width` and `min-height` to set the minimal width and height of a web page, when u try to resize the window.
See snippet blow.

also i have put the html in [dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/juloe9sy8qxc558/demo.html?dl=0). the min-width works in chrome not in IE, the min-height doesn't work at all. What's wrong with my code? Any help would be appreciated.

```css
body {
  min-width: 330px; <!-- This only works in chrome not work in IE -->
  min-height: 400px; <!-- This doesn't work at all. -->
}
fieldset {
  border:5px;
}
select {
  width: 100px;
}
input {
  width: 195px;
}
input, select {
  height: 30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}
table {
  width: 300px;
}
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
#powered {
  margin-left: 60px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <div class="main">
      <form id="form_converter" action="#">
        <fieldset>
          <label>For test, not integrated yet.</label>
          <br>
          <select id="select_currency1" onchange="currency1Changed()">
            <option>USD</option>
            <option>EUR</option>
            <option selected="selected">SGD</option>
            <option>JPY</option>
            <option>CNY</option>
          </select>
          <input type="text" id="currency1" class="number">
          <br>
          <select id="select_currency2" onchange="currency2Changed()">
            <option selected="selected">USD</option>
            <option>EUR</option>
            <option>SGD</option>
            <option>JPY</option>
            <option>CNY</option>
          </select>
          <input type="text" id="currency2" class="number">
          <br>
          <br>
          <table>
            <tr>
              <th>Currency</th>
              <th>Code</th>
              <th>Value</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>SGD</td>
              <td>SGD</td>
              <td>1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>USD</td>
              <td>USD</td>
              <td>0.7</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>EUR</td>
              <td>EUR</td>
              <td>0.6</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>JPY</td>
              <td>JPY</td>
              <td>82.063</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>CNY</td>
              <td>CNY</td>
              <td>4.7</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </fieldset>
      </form>
    </div>
  <body>
<html>
```

Comment: Are you trying to limit the size of the browser window? The min-height seems to be working as expected in your example.

Comment: yes i want to limit the size of the browser window.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think it's fully possible to restrict the user from resizing the window - see [Setting minimum size limit for a window minimization of browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16173965/setting-minimum-size-limit-for-a-window-minimization-of-browser). You can force it with a popup but `min-height` only applies to HTML elements, not the browser window itself.

Possibly an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16173965/setting-minimum-size-limit-for-a-window-minimization-of-browser/16174183#16174183) that might help.

Answer (score 0):

Do not directly set the body width or height, make the size of body as reference for other element. if you want to set the minimum of width or height just use a container.

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  min-width: 60%;
  min-height: 70%;
}
```

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

## **Use `@media` in CSS**

Take a look at [`@media`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media) CSS at-rule.

You can use `@media screen and (max-width: 330px)` and `@media screen and (max-height: 400px)` and set with of your html component to keep you're page always up to 330px with and 400px height. After, if you want users can access the masked content of your page set `overflow:auto`.

You can't prevent user resize his browser under this values but you're web page will never go under the values you select.

The CSS can look like that :

```
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 330px) {
  html {
      width: 330px;
      overflow: auto;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-height: 400px) {
  html {
      height: 400px;
      overflow: auto;
  }
}
```