# Create a drop down which extends beyond the browser window

Tags: jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I've a typical drop down in an html page with position absolute inside a relatively positioned parent.When I reduced the size of the browser window (making it very small) and click on the drop down, the latter does open but it's visible area is limited to the browser viewport.

I want to make the drop down completely visible even if it means a portion of the drop down is visible outside the browser window.

Here's my code so far:

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $("#side-caret").click(function() {
    $(".side-caret-drop-down").css("display", "block");
  });
});
```

```css
.file-menu {
  background-color: #99CCFF;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}

.file-menu-item {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  color: black;
  margin: 1px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}

.file-menu-drop-down {
  display: block;
  padding-left: 3px;
  padding-right: 3px;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.side-caret {
  float: left;
  margin: 2px;
  position: relative;
}

.side-caret-drop-down {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  border: solid black 1px;
  background-color: #FFF8DC;
}

.side-caret-drop-down a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.clearfix {
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
}

.file-menu>.file-menu-item:hover {
  background-color: white;
}

.file-content {
  white-space: pre;
  overflow: auto;
}

.file-menu .file-menu-item.selected {
  background-color: white;
}

body {
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="top"></div>
<div id="left"></div>
<div id="content">
  <div class="file-menu">
    <a class="file-menu-item" href="#" title="dummy">HelloWorld.java</a>
    <a class="file-menu-item" href="#" title="dummy">Base.java</a>
    <div id="side-caret" class="side-caret">
      <a class="file-menu-drop-down" href="#" title="Drop Down">
        <font size="1"><sup>&#8811;</sup><span id="counter">1</span></font>
      </a>
      <div class="side-caret-drop-down">
        <a class="file-menu-item" href="#" title="dummy">Derived1111111111111111111111111111111111.java</a>
        <a class="file-menu-item" href="#" title="dummy">Derived2222222222222222222222222222222222.java</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="file-content">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: We are not here to write the code for you. Come back when you have a specific question about a piece of code. Or add the code you already have to the question

Comment: You should read the [How To Ask A Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) knowledge object before asking questions.

Comment: @CodeSpent, apologies if my question is not clear. But I think the title is quite obvious.Anyway, I'm new to web development and not a frequent user of stackoverflow, so probably I was not clear in the above question.Let me make amends. As suggested, I'm including a JSFiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/mcfztb5u/2/ .Open the link and look at the html output.Click on ">>1". It opens a drop down. Now minimize chrome window.One can see the drop down clipped by the browser viewport. Now I need to show the drop down in full even if it protrudes outside the browser's viewport. Help needed !!

Comment: 1. Whether or not it's obvious doesn't matter, include your code always. Show effort. 2. Your jsfiddle 404s so get a good link and include a code snippet in your question. Read the article I sent you.

Comment: What you're asking for here is not possible.  There is no way for a web page to render anything outside the boundaries of the browser window.

Comment: The default dropdown window cannot extend out of browser boundary, but you can create your own dropdown using `span` that acts like the default dropdown menu. That can extend to out of browser window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot display anything outside of a browser window, everything is clipped to it.

However, what you *can* do is to set a [minimum width](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min-width) and [height](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min-height). This will prevent the browser from shrinking down beyond a size you determine.

```
body {
  min-width: 500px;
}
```

What that will do is to guarantee a scroll bar if the window is shrunk beyond that width. You can also consider this "trick" to make a new popup with a hardcoded size: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16174183/3029173

Comment: Useful hack. Exactly what I was looking for. The question edit looks very good too.

Comment: Just checked now. The horizontal scroll bar appears by default in chrome when the drop down is opened with the window shrunk to a very small size.Serves my purpose