# Set maximum browser resizing width for whole website

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

When someone resizing browser window like this, I need to set minimum width. So users can't resize no more smaller. Is this css way or JS?

I tried doing some js work, using this script and modified it but no luck.

```
window.onresize = function() {
    if (window.innerWidth < 900) {
        window.resizeTo(1024);
    }
};
```

How do I do this?

[image]

Comment: `I need to set maximum width. So users can't resize no more smaller` ??
Do you mean Minimum width ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting minimum size limit for a window minimization of browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16173965/setting-minimum-size-limit-for-a-window-minimization-of-browser)

Comment: @zey Sorry my bad. Edited

Comment: The question is why? not how! You should **never** try to change the behaviour of core OS level functionality. There's good reason as to why you shouldn't and why you can't.

Comment: @zey As you can see, I don't want to make any changes to height, it will work as auto, only width needs to set to minimum width.

Comment: @zey If you are suggesting NO to this requirement, then why I cannot resize airbnb? it's not going more than 477px but other websites possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can't/shouldn't force the user to keep the browser window itself at a particular size, but you can set the minimum size of the web page to whatever you like using CSS like:

```
body{ min-width: 500px; }
```

Here's a working example of that with a couple of styled divs. (If the user shrinks the window below the size of your content, some of your content is hidden until they increase the window's width again, but your content is otherwise unaffected.)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <style>
    body{ min-width: 600px; background-color: lightskyblue }
    div{ margin: 0 auto; border: 1px solid gray; }
    .outer{ width: 100%; height: 300px; background-color: #DDDDDD; }
    .inner{ width: 60%; margin-top: 20px; background-color: white; text-align: center }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">Words Words Words</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

You stated that you wanted to affect the whole website, which would just require moving your CSS to an external style sheet and linking to it from each page on the site.

See also the answers to this similar question:
[Setting minimum size limit for a window minimization of browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16173965/setting-minimum-size-limit-for-a-window-minimization-of-browser)