# how to set the minimum size of browser window

Tags: html, css

i am making a web site and i don't want client to decrease the size of browser window

i want a minimum size of browser so it won't shrink more of that

i tried min-width and min-height of my body but it won't work

```
body{
    min-width: 500px;
    min-height: 500px;
}
```

[this is the link for my website that won't fixed size](https://jsfiddle.net/AliBalouchi/w7ckds9j/)

any idea would be appreciated

thanks

Comment: i did that but it won't work for height

Answer (score 1):

What you apparently looking for is to restrict **not the viewport** but **the browser window itself** in size. This is not possible to implement properly because of browser restrictions — which is a good thing since otherwise lots of nefarious stuff would be implemented this way.

Again: you can limit the viewport in size but not a proper browser window itself.

For additional info see this question: [Setting minimum size limit for a window minimization of browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16173965/setting-minimum-size-limit-for-a-window-minimization-of-browser)

Answer (score 1):

A web page **does not** and ***should not*** have the permission to resize the browser window.

But the web page does have the right to decide when and how to display its contents.
So here's a simple CSS solution:

```css
.warning-message {
  display: none;
}
.content-wrapper {
  display: block;
}
@media (max-height: 399px), (max-width: 599px){
  .warning-message {
    display: block;
  }
  .content-wrapper {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="warning-message">
  Make window bigger to view contents.
</div>
<div class="content-wrapper">
  <h1>That's better...</h1>
  <p>Resize the browser window below a height of <code>400px</code> or a width of <code>600px</code> and you won't see the content anymore. 
  </p>A warning message will be displayed.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<meta name="viewport" user-scalable="no" />
```

> use meta viewport with user-scalable attribute set to no

Comment: it won't work on my site and i want user resize browser if he/she wants but not more from 500px

Comment: yo want your page to shrink on devices with a small screen size and not to over expand on devices with larger screen sizes

Comment: i want my window get big for how the client want and small for how the client want but not smaller than 500px

Comment: @john, meta viewport's `user-scalable="no"` prevents users from zooming in or out (`Ctrl/Cmd`+`+`), (`Ctrl/Cmd`+`-`). It has nothing to do with browser window size.

Comment: this question was rephrased

Comment: Not according to [SO]. The question is in its original form.