# min-height or min-width or responsive won't work

Tags: html, css

I want to create a layer from windows 10 calculator and i have some problem in height and width in it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Problems:

1. when i pull up the top of the result or increase the height of the browseer the calculator go up and a large space appear in the bottom of the calculator and i don't know why is that.
2. when i decrease the width of the window instead of decrease the width of buttons calculator go right and some buttons won't display.
3. when i decrease the height of window it won't stop any where but i want to stop it in 500 px height;

This is my code.

**html**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="./calculator.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <title>Windows10 Calculator</title>
          <script id="MathJax-script" async
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js"> 
</script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="calculator-container">
                <div class="top-navbar">
                    <p id="calculator">
                        Calculator
                    </p>
                    <div class="close-bar">
                        <a id="minimize">-</a>
                        <a id="maximize"></a>
                        <a id="close">x</a> 
                    </div>
                </div>

            <div class="calculator-screen">
                <div class="top-screen">
                    <a id="calculator-menu">≡</a>
                    <p id="standard">
                        Standard
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="result"><span id="result">4</span></div>
                <div class="m-row">
                    <a id="MC">MC</a>
                    <a id="MR">MR</a>
                    <a id="Mplus">M+</a>
                    <a id="Mminus">M-</a>
                    <a id="MS">MS</a>
                </div>
                </div>

                <hr />

                <div class="functions">
                    <div class="row">
                        <a class="hide-in-big blue">%</a>
                        <a class="hide-in-big blue">√</a>
                        <a class="lucida-font hide-in-big blue"><p>
                        x<sup>2</sup>
                        </p></a>
                        <a class="lucida-font hide-in-big blue"><p><sup>1</sup>&#8725;<sub>x</sub></p></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <a class="show-in-big blue">%</a>
                        <a class="cs blue">CE</a>
                        <a class="cs blue">C</a>
                        <a class="blue"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACAAAAAgCAYAAABzenr0AAABDklEQVRYR+2W4Q3CIBSErxu4iY6gm+hmbqIj6CZuUHNJMeQFeAelaUzoT8LjPo570Ak7f9PO+hgAw4G/cuAA4AHg1KFzfhtXHegpTv4qgFj8DeAM4NPowrzUyQA9xaldBaCIc451IzUWDJMBFPE7gCOASwQR6l4AboljkgAUcc55LgAUIwS/0CW5rLgAinjYmIXgOFu0FNQiQI14CoJjXpe4ANZWr93s/RCOI1cnHYEKYR2jAwxlCcIF4CKpgKVazQaOtR68BKBCsA0ZuvhmDPB04drahrmUx/0ez9nkIqqBqHkW5COIF1UyoUI0AdhMqGKlefJrmHNiLUQTwFrRZL36R7SJOBcdAMOB3R34AqM1YCEu+sgCAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC" /></a>
                        <a class="hover-blue blue">\[\div\]</a>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="numpad">
                    <div class="row">
                        <a class="lucida-font show-in-big blue">√</a>
                        <a class="number">7</a>
                        <a class="number">8</a>
                        <a class="number">9</a>
                        <a class="hover-blue blue">&times;</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <a class="lucida-font show-in-big blue"><p>
                        x<sup>2</sup>
                        </p>
                        <a class="number">4</a>
                        <a class="number">5</a>
                        <a class="number">6</a>
                        <a class="hover-blue blue">-</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <a class="lucida-font show-in-big blue"><p>
                        x<sup>3</sup>
                        </p></a>
                        <a class="number">1</a>
                        <a class="number">2</a>
                        <a class="number">3</a>
                        <a class="hover-blue blue">&plus;</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <a class="lucida-font show-in-big blue"><p><sup>1</sup>&#8725;<sub>x</sub></p></a>
                        <a class="blue">&plusmn;</a>
                        <a class="number">0</a>
                        <a class="blue">&#8729;</a>
                        <a class="hover-blue blue">&equals;</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="history-memory">
            <div>
                <div class="hidden-close-bar">
                    <a id="minimize">ー</a>
                    <a id="maximize"></a>
                    <a id="close">྾</a> 
                </div>
                <div class="history-memory-bar">
                    <a id="history">History</a>
                    <a id="memory">Memory</a>
                </div>
            </div>
                <div class="history-memory-screen">
                  <span class="grey"> 2&#215;2=</span>
                  <span class="black">4</span>
                   <span class="grey">9999+1=</span>
                   <span class="black">10000</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

**CSS**:

```
@font-face{
  src: 
url("//db.onlinewebfonts.com/t/efbd8f0d869bf61fbe0f139a1602cda8.woff2");
  font-family:"lucida calligraphy";
}

body{
 min-width: 500px;
  width: auto !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: Segoe UI;
}

.close-bar, .hidden-close-bar{
  margin-right: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.container{
 min-width: 800px;
  min-height: 800px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  background-color: #E6E6E6;
}

.calculator-container{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between !important;
}

.top-navbar{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.top-navbar p {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.top-screen a{
  font-size: 2em;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.top-screen p{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.calculator-screen{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.top-screen{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.top-screen * {
  margin: 1%;
  font-size: 2em;
}

.result{
  height: 15vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  font-size: 4em;
  font-family: Segoe UI;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.row{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: bottom
}

.cs{
  font-size: 1.5em !important;
}

.m-row{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: start;
  align-items: center;
}

.m-row a{
  margin-left: 7%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#standard{
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin-left: 3%;
}

.row a {
  width: 25%;
  height: 10%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 10vh;
  margin: 1px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 2em;
}

.row a:hover{
  background-color: #B1B2B5;
}

.blue{
  background-color: #F0F0F0;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.number{
  background-color: #FAFAFA;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.5em !important;
}

.history-memory{
  display: none;
}

.history-memory a {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

.row .hide-in-big{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.row .show-in-big{
  display: none;
}

.hidden-close-bar{
  display: none;
}

 .close-bar {
    margin: 1px;
  }

  #history {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #0097A7;
    margin-right: 10%;
  }

  #trash-can {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 10px;
    background-color: #aad3ef;
    cursor: default;
  }

  #trash-can img {
    width: 15%;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #aad3ef;
  }

  .history-memory-screen{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    margin-top: 10%;
    height: 100%;
  }

  .history-memory-bar{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: flex-start;
  }

  .grey{
    align-self: flex-end;
    color: #616161;
    margin: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
  }

  .black{
    align-self: flex-end;
    justify-self: flex-end;
    margin: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
  }

  .lucida-font{
    font-family:"lucida calligraphy" !important;
    font-size: 1em !important;
    font-weight: bold !important;
  }

  .hover-blue:hover{
     background-color: #1C87DB !important;
     color: white;
     display: flex;
     justify-content: center;
     align-items: center;
  }

@media screen and (max-width: 800px){
  .calculator-container{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%
  }

  .row .show-in-big{
    display: none;
  }

  .row .hide-in-big {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width:800px){

  .history-memory{
    display: flex;
    width: 40%;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }

  .hidden-close-bar{
    display: block;
    text-align: right;
  }

  .hidden-close-bar a{
    margin: 1px;
  }

  .close-bar {
    display: none;
  }

}

@media screen and (min-width: 1000px){
  .row .hide-in-big{
    display: none;
  }

  .row .show-in-big {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
}
```

and [this is](http://jsfiddle.net/AliBalouchi/qsm69vdy/) the link to jsfiddle of my code

Comment: Most people aren't going to bother reading through a really long bit of code like this and working it all out. 

The best thing to do, is to reproduce the same issue in the smallest way possible and post that as a stack overflow embed.

Comment: @dwjohnston thanks for advice but my main problem is i don't know what's wrong in code

Answer (score 0):

**problem number 1:** since you use `min-height`, you should define the `height` of your paren. In your case it is `body` so this will solve the 1st problem:

```css
body{
  /* other stuff */
  height: 100vh; /* or whatever px, em, etc., except % */
}
```

**problem number 2:** As I understand, the problem appears with the 'M' buttons, since all others seem to be resized correctly... so if you add `max-width` to the `.m-row a` it would prevent overflow. You also could add the `font-size` in `vw` as you did for the other buttons, though I wouldn't do this because all the texts become unreadable in a small window.

```css
.m-row a{
  margin-left: 7%;
  max-width: 13%; /* because you have 5 buttons (each 20%) - 7% of your margin-left*/
}
```

**problem number 3:** You could open a new window with specified dimensions with [some javascript and control it's size with `window.resizeTo`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16174183/11915216). However I think some browsers won't allow this.. So instead I would simply add `min-width`, `min-height` add `overflow: auto` to the parent (in your case the body).

I hope it helps.